# How to output the name of the same values in a array?

Tags: php

I have the following `array()`

```
$statoA = array();
```

It has

```
Italy
France
France
Italy
Spain
```

I know I can use `array_count_values($statoA)`

But how to do a `foreach` to have:

```
<ul>
  <li>2 France</li>
  <ll>2 Italy</li>
  <li>1 Spain</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: just use the results from array_count_values($statoA) in the foreach loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(array_count_values($statoA) as $k=>$v){
    echo '<li>'.$v.' '.$k.'</li>';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `array_count_values()`, then you will have a array where the keys are the terms from your original array, and the values are the counts for each term. You can then loop through this array to build your markup:

```
<ul>
    <?php
        foreach (array_count_values($statoA) as $key => $value) {
            //$key is now the term (France, Italy, Spain)
            //$value is now the frequency or counts of the term
            echo "<li>{$value} {$key}</li>";
        }
    ?>
</ul>
```

Documentation for `array_count_values` is available here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Documentation on `foreach` is available here: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: @thanks a lot, this helped me more than the other answer but since it is basically the same and the other answer came first I had to accept the previous. Said that, thanks a lot because I've learned due to your explanation :)

Comment: No worries, happy to be of service

Comment: PHP has a code style standard that is opt-in, but highly recommended, maintained by the PHP-FIG group. In the code style standard, PSR-2, all control structures use braces and are never placed on a single line, for readability and consistency (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#control-structures). Section 5.6 of the standard is specifically for the foreach control structure, and states it should look as it does in my answer (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/#foreach). I always try to answer within the standard to keep things, well...standardized.

Comment: im not talking about the foreach, but `{$value}` and `{$key}`

Comment: That's for two considerations, mainly - readability, and consistency across all data types. I find it easier, personally, to pick the variables out, and my IDE will color hint as well. For consistency, it's handy when you want to do something like `echo "Name: {$user->name}."`. I find that more agreeable than than dot-concatenation (again, personally). Eventually I just got in the habit of doing it regardless of the data type in the variable. If there are no variables to interpret in the string, I also go so far as to specifically use apostrophes instead of quotes. Just marks intent well.